# Remove Select Dropdown option based on previous selection of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I know there are a few examples I have looked through on here but I am still not able to get my jquery to work correctly.

**Question:** If user selects a specific option from dropdown #1 then change the options in dropdown #2 How is this accomplished?

**HTML/Coldfusion:**

```
<label>*Xpress Mod/Paint:</label> <cfselect name="xpress_mod_data">
<option value="Non-Xpress">Non Xpress 
<option value="3-Day">3-Day Xpress
</cfselect>

<label>Enclosure Type:</label> <cfselect name="enclosure_type">
<option value="global">Global 
<option value="server_optimized">Server Optimized 
</cfselect>
```

**This is my JQuery:**

```
$('#xpress_mod_data').change(function() {

        if($(this).attr("value")=="3-Day") {
            $("#enclosure_type option[value='server_optimized']").remove();
        } else {
        $('#enclosure_type').append('<option value="server_optimized">Server Optimized');
        }

});
```

**What is happening when I run my code:** The option that is supposed to be appended keeps getting added over and over again.

Comment: Side note, if you are already using jquery, ditch the `cfselect` and use a plain html `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didnt use id in your html `id="xpress_mod_data"` this one is missing [Check Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctrxcpe0/)

Html

```
   <select name="xpress_mod_data" id="xpress_mod_data">
        <option value="Non-Xpress">Non Xpress </option>
    <option value="3-Day">3-Day Xpress</option>
    </select>

    <label>Enclosure Type:</label>  
    <select name="enclosure_type" id="enclosure_type">
    <option value="global">Global  </option>
    <option value="server_optimized">Server Optimized  </option>
    </select>
```

Jquery

```
$('#xpress_mod_data').change(function() {

 if($(this).val()=="3-Day") {
     console.log('test');
            $("#enclosure_type option[value='server_optimized']").remove();
        } else {
        $('#enclosure_type').append('<option value="server_optimized">Server Optimized');
        }

});
```

Comment: Thank you sir for pointing that out not sure why or how I missed it for so long. Thought name was enough for some reason. +1 and checked.

Comment: *Thought name was enough for some reason* FYI, the `#` in front of "xpress_mod_data"  means it is an id. See ["id" selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

For greater flexibility in case you need to add multiple chained selects,  have multiple parents or use Ajax to build the drop-downs, check out the jQuery Chained Selects plugin.  (It greatly simplified a project where I needed 5 possible drop-downs working together.)

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained